# how can we create different home page for different community in DSpace jspui?

Tags: dspace

i m working on DSpace JSPUI customization . i just want to make different home pages for different communities. it is possible in XMLUI by using themes but how it can be done in JSPUI ??

Comment: In community-home.jsp page we have handle <%= community.getHandle() %> on the basis of this handle we have change the logo on this page ??

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to show a different logo for each community, you can do that by uploading the appropriate logo via the Edit Community screen. That screen also gives you some options for adding text to the community page.

If you want bigger differences than that, the community home page is created in this file: https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/dspace-5.1/dspace-jspui/src/main/webapp/community-home.jsp You could edit that file to render different things based on the community's handle.

If you want your customisations in a different file, eg the header / footer, you could change the appropriate JSP file to find the community like in community-home.jsp ([here](https://github.com/DSpace/DSpace/blob/dspace-5.1/dspace-jspui/src/main/webapp/community-home.jsp#L40))

```
Community community = (Community) request.getAttribute( "community" );
```

then check whether that community is a valid object. If so, retrieve its handle and take it from there.

Comment: I just want to change the page logo not the community logo. Logo which is  set in header-default page i want to change that on community basis.

Comment: You might like to change your question to reflect what you're trying to do. That way, you'll increase your chances of someone posting a helpful answer.